# Mongoose array not saving JSON object

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongoose

I'm trying to save a JSON object in my User schema array called 'pictures'.
When I call the REST API route to save an object, it saves but whatever I have saved previously within the array is erased.
Why are the previous elements in the array being erased?  Is something not saving correctly?
My schema's array starts out with a default of 4 empty strings in the array.
The rank is the index within the array I want to store the new 'picture' at.

Here's the API route:

```
router.post('/uploadImage', tokenAuthorizer, async (req, res) => {
    let { rank, link } = req.body;
    const userID = req.id;

    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ _id: userID });
        if (!user) throw new Error('Could not find user');

        // object to save
        const picture = {
            link: link,
            rank: rank,
        };

        // store at index 'rank'
        user.pictures[rank] = picture;

        await user.save();
        res.json({ msg: user });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        res.status(500).json({ msg: e.message });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your `req.body` and `req.id` along with the document you're trying to modify?

Comment: the `id` is being put in through a the tokenAuthorizer middleware function.
It's working perfectly and has been verified in other API routes.  I think it's an issue of my understanding on how Mongoose arrays work.

Comment: Can you share your schema? It looks like `pictures` is an array of strings and you're trying to save an object.